# Making Quartz.net work with log4net 1.2.11.0

Tags: version, log4net, quartz.net, common.logging

I'm using Quartz.net for a project, which depends on Common.Logging 2.0. Problem is, that Common.Logging 2.0 only works with log4net 1.2.10.0, and we got libraries that depends on log4net 1.2.11.0.

Has anyone had problems with this? I can't really find a lot of information about Common.Logging 2.0 vs. log4net 1.2.11.0 yet. Any ideas how solve it, or am I SOL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing [assembly redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This should let you use version 1.2.11 and redirect all requests for version 1.2.10 to 1.2.11.

Comment: Never heard about that before. Thanks a lot!